# Integrating Custom Context Provider in Astro Framework - Missing ReactDOM.createRoot

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on an Astro framework-based project and facing challenges while integrating a custom context provider. Specifically, I need to wrap my app with the MyModule context provider, but I don't have access to ReactDOM.createRoot in my Astro-based application.

Issue Details:
I have a custom context provider called MyModule, which I want to use to provide certain functionalities and state management throughout my application. Typically, in a traditional React app, I would use ReactDOM.createRoot to render the app and wrap it with the context provider like this:

```
// index.js (React entry point)
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { MyModule } from './MyModule';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <MyModule>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </MyModule>
);
```

However, in my Astro-based project, I don't have an equivalent index.js file, and I'm not sure how to wrap my app with the MyModule context provider.

Code Sample (Simplified):
In my Astro project, I don't have the traditional index.js file to place the above code:

```
// ??? (Astro equivalent)
import React from 'react';
import { MyModule } from './MyModule';
import App from './App';

// How can I wrap my app with MyModule context provider here?

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyModule>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
      </MyModule>
    </>
  );
}
```

1. How can I access ReactDOM.createRoot in an Astro-based application?
2. Where should I place the initialization code for the MyModule context provider in my Astro project to achieve similar functionality as in a traditional React app?
3. Is there an Astro-specific approach to handle custom context providers and wrapping the app with them?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: see this, I have tried and working as expected -> https://community.apollographql.com/t/accessing-apollo-client-in-an-astro-react-project-without-apolloprovider/3943/8